# How do I display my html mail?

Tags: php, html-email

I am writing a code for a school project that sends an automatic email (and some other things).

I thought that it would be a good idea to write an html-email so I did that, but then I found that when the email is sent, it contains nothing but the title and the headers.

I already tried php.ini, but that's no good, since I'm using the FTP-server of my school and I don't have permission to do that kind of things.

---

The code underneath is the particular part of my php that this is about.

```php
<?php
  $headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
  $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
  $headers .= "From: ymackor <noreply.ymackor@gmail.com>\r\n";
  $headers .= "BCC: noreply.ymackor@gmail.com\r\n";

  $message  = "<html><head><style>table{border-collapse:collapse;border:2px solid black;}tr,td{border-width:1px 0;border-style:solid;border-color:dimgray;padding:0 10px;border-left:.5px solid lightgray;border-right:.5px solid lightgray;text-align:left;style></head><body>";
  $message .= "<h2>Your order is handled and sent, it will arrive in 12 hours:</h2>";
  $message .= "<table> <tr> <th> Product </th> <th> Quantity </th> <th> Price </th> </tr>";
  foreach ($product as $i => $x) {
    $message .= "<tr> <td> " . $product_name[$i] . " </td> <td> " . $x . " </td> <td> " . money_format("%^#10.2n", $product_price[$i]) . " </td> </tr>";
  }
  $message .= "<tr> <th> <u>Total:</u> </th> <th> " . array_sum($product) . " </th> <th> " . money_format("%^#10.2n", array_sum($product_price));
  $message .= "</table>";
  $message .= "</body></html>";

  mail($_POST["email"], "NO-REPLY: Your order", $message, $headers);
?>
```

and this is my email sourcecode:

```
Delivered-To: yannick.mackor@gmail.com
Received: by 2002:a6b:7110:0:0:0:0:0 with SMTP id q16-v6csp459335iog;
        Mon, 25 Jun 2018 02:37:59 -0700 (PDT)
X-Google-Smtp-Source: ADUXVKIPxPM3xq+h6PvxFCto0awYtGAIWLE+HLAWmZA2IWQJe7wA2w8LqLGsAEfNPc0iFt3leNeC
X-Received: by 2002:a50:96d1:: with SMTP id z17-v6mr10591217eda.55.1529919479460;
        Mon, 25 Jun 2018 02:37:59 -0700 (PDT)
ARC-Seal: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; t=1529919479; cv=none;
        d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        b=anlEjH3PMUMyGvY2jLrIDXs+frMsdSb8zmigcgmxybAEQPv+yxiM9GPfI0nM1La+iZ
         shqeg1I/efpMdOx2bLpqaQfctSAL+kerh0ISFBIg9ojnN1JVpkVZxIzNOGmelPFSGODV
         NkAvsKKKC0yIUuTNvsLg+4sCJ3aGnaElrdMsIp0hhNmdZxbSq2AtBu9vQnpvw3eAVG3h
         JaVISgiq1SOYlSACKLbPpN7TeyIzmYRjWMPZimmAoLW2u81hH6Qeb2sZfbFLkL8OClJx
         zrNIVbkxzVnANtEBioWKWEjA0KxXcgflJjjp8796H+hCHkZYdBGHfZWMQ3i/7vxFc3kQ
         grUQ==
ARC-Message-Signature: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        h=date:sender:message-id:from:mime-version:subject:to
         :arc-authentication-results;
        bh=PYQtoENArjkziK1+qiQVdq1Wz83XImd871/k1vmO/XM=;
        b=j4esNHXiikbTqzvS1GPcZKqbMRPUNvpk99OKjxBLnIszLMyr+USRLYAWyc8YMH1W4l
         PtktDEROGgxLZvp6nLhumBMlF2QWZuMdbH2wyvuTnuDaAJCH1haHTaeaLw05yK4mDLSu
         YgyzFXU3hDSH07F5hXx3GjaWh49e6Edh+WXz6s1ocCN2qDKzFHPQmrXBHLMufqlrvWXT
         8tE0wFaQ0Sbx1daXX0NIMVvLIrE3GXcla+0Nc8BbqlOK+TGhT0HDGZgZ/UAhqMwZQP73
         FJPds4DaxF2iOXOtTPae3tu0+GJvOcbCfQS9c632kVeZvxJPCLpTQ6eiToSCmeGBc7FU
         fFEA==
ARC-Authentication-Results: i=1; mx.google.com;
       spf=pass (google.com: best guess record for domain of cals@da01.informatica-cals.nl designates 87.233.228.82 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=cals@da01.informatica-cals.nl;
       dmarc=fail (p=NONE sp=QUARANTINE dis=NONE) header.from=gmail.com
Return-Path: <cals@da01.informatica-cals.nl>
Received: from da01.informatica-cals.nl (da01.informatica-cals.nl. [87.233.228.82])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id n12-v6si977002edr.216.2018.06.25.02.37.59
        (version=TLS1 cipher=AES128-SHA bits=128/128);
        Mon, 25 Jun 2018 02:37:59 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: best guess record for domain of cals@da01.informatica-cals.nl designates 87.233.228.82 as permitted sender) client-ip=87.233.228.82;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=pass (google.com: best guess record for domain of cals@da01.informatica-cals.nl designates 87.233.228.82 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=cals@da01.informatica-cals.nl;
       dmarc=fail (p=NONE sp=QUARANTINE dis=NONE) header.from=gmail.com
Received: from cals by da01.informatica-cals.nl with local (Exim 4.80.1) (envelope-from <cals@da01.informatica-cals.nl>) id 1fXNwd-0001xF-45; Mon, 25 Jun 2018 11:37:59 +0200
To: yannick.mackor@gmail.com
Subject: NO-REPLY: Your order
X-PHP-Script: informatica-cals.nl/ymackor/webshop/bestelform.php for 83.128.169.172
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
From: ymackor <noreply.ymackor@gmail.com>
X-Mailer: PHP/5.2.17
Message-Id: <E1fXNwd-0001xF-45@da01.informatica-cals.nl>
Sender: <cals@da01.informatica-cals.nl>
Date: Mon, 25 Jun 2018 11:37:59 +0200

<html><head><style>table{border-collapse:collapse;border:2px solid black;}tr,td{border-width:1px 0;border-style:solid;border-color:dimgray;padding:0 10px;border-left:.5px solid lightgray;border-right:.5px solid lightgray;text-align:left;style></head><body><h2>Your order is handled and sent, it will arrive in 12 hours:</h2><table> <tr> <th> Product </th> <th> Quantity </th> <th> Price </th> </tr><tr> <td> Ice popsicle </td> <td> 10 </td> <td>  $         0.95 </td> </tr><tr> <td> Hot chocolate </td> <td> 12 </td> <td>  $         9.50 </td> </tr><tr> <td> Self-destructing alarm clock </td> <td> 13 </td> <td>  $       115.00 </td> </tr><tr> <th> <u>Total:</u> </th> <th> 35 </th> <th>  $       125.45</table></body></html>
```

Comment: _“I already tried php.ini”_ - regarding what exactly? What configuration setting do you think would/could come into play here?

Comment: Go check the actual source code of the received email. Does it contains the values you are trying to output dynamically in the relevant places? And do you have proper PHP error reporting enabled? If not, go and do that first!

Comment: I made a php.ini in my topmost folder and wrote `mail.add_x_header = 1` in it

Comment: As a side note, I would rather search some tools (eg: [phpmailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)) first, because reinventing the wheel is not a good idea in the first place, as simple `mail()` is going to make your life hard.

Comment: @MihaiIorga true if you're implementing an enterprise application or whatever but this is stated as a school project, so actually diving a bit deeper into the guts of everything to understand a little more of the detail is no bad thing IMHO. If every student just uses a library to to everything in their apps, then they never understand how those things work, and then they will presumably find it harder to acquire the skills needed to be the person who creates/maintains the library in future, and then those skills will gradually die away...

Comment: The sourcecode of the email is fine as far as I can see

Comment: @ADyson not really, understanding everything like you say would take ages :). If you get really interested into a project then you can go deeper, get to understand the basics, but I don't think you really need to know the basics to everything. In this case, `mail()` turns to be a pain if environment is not set correctly.

Comment: @MihaiIorga I have to use `mail()`, it's one of the requirements of the project

Comment: @MihaiIorga of course, it's not possible to understand _everything_ :-). But it's useful to dive deeper into some things at least, then you get an idea of how some lower-level stuff works. It sounds like Yannick has been told to use this function without a wrapper, presumably for the exact purpose of working with something more awkward. You can often learn more by struggling. The objective of a student project is not usually to implement the slickest app possible in the shortest time, but to gain an understanding of some fundamental principles instead. Anyway, it was just a passing remark.

Comment: @ADyson Mihailorga I'd rather get help then a debate about learning, excuse me for being so blunt.

Comment: @YannickMackor "The sourcecode of the email is fine"...you mean it contains all the `<html><head>`...etc content you included? Where are you viewing it - what email client are you using? Different email clients have varying implementations of HTML unfortunately, and often display things in different ways. Occasionally you might even still find one which only supports text-based emails. It might help if you could post a copy of the whole email source code including the headers, and also state what client(s) you have tested this with.

Comment: @ADyson I use gmail

Comment: ok well in theory it should be display a HTML mail quite nicely. So please answer my other questions and/or edit your question to include the extra content, so we can start to understand things in more detail. Thanks.

Comment: `<th>  $       125.45</table>` in the output...your HTML is invalid. You need to close the th and the tr surrounding it. Correct the HTML and try again. BTW this is also semantically problematic - the `th` element is intended for header rows and titles, not for data. If you want something to appear in bold in your table, add the appropriate CSS instead.

Comment: @ADyson thanx, i'll try

Comment: @YannickMackor what was the outcome?

Comment: @ADyson it was fixed, thanks

Comment: @YannickMackor ok then great. I suggest you write this as the answer, and show the changes you made to your code. You are allowed to accept your own answer...and others are allowed to upvote it

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work, it looks like there's nothing wrong with the code, but with PHP Configuration or Mail configuration.
I also recommend using PHPMailer since it actually gives you nice status feedback and it is object oriented.

You could run the mail command on SSH just to see if it works through the command.

Comment: can't do that, have to stick with the builtins